# Error when using the original crowdsale code

Tags: crowdsale

I have copied the original [crowd sale code from the Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale) website and pasted it in the solidity contract source code field. Code is untouched, precisely as on the Ethereum website. For some reason the network says `could not compile source code` and `Expected token Semicolon got 'eth_compileSolidity' uint amount += msg.value;`

I have tried to restart the Ethereum wallet but nothing works.

Comment: What editor are you using? What compiler version? It compiles just fine in Remix.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the + in

```
uint amount += msg.value;
```

I changed it to

```
uint amount = msg.value;
```

It makes more sense if you ask me since you don't need to keep incrementing the value of amount every time someone gives Ether in a Crowdsale.

Comment: I don't see such line in the example?